# How to detect Core Data Object relationship property changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In My FRC Im fetching **Posts**.
**Posts** have many **Photo**s
I need to detect when a property of **Photo** (totalLikes) changes so i can update my tableview.

I know that I can monitor changes with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

But im not sure how to see if that notification contains photo.totalLikes changes and then to which Post that Photo belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`. In its `userInfo` it passes all the changed objects (use `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` to get them). Then and make use of `changedValues` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/changedValues):

```
//in a notification handler
for(NSManagedObject *object in notification.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
    if([object isKindOfClass:[Photo class]]) {
      //if you get non-nil value it means that totalLikes has changed
      id newLikesValue = [object changedValues][@"totalLikes"];
    }
}
```

If you want to know which Post that Photo belongs to, just use the inverse relationship (it is recommended to set one anyway).